# How to get selected rows id in ng-grid(AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I wish deleted selected rows.so i want to get selected ids

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    enablePaging: true,
    showSelectionCheckbox :true,
    resizable :true,
    showFooter: true,
    multiSelect: true,
    selectedItems:$scope.mySelections,
    totalServerItems:'totalServerItems',
    pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
    filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
    afterSelectionChange: function () {
      $scope.selectedIDs = []; 
      angular.forEach($scope.mySelections, function ( item ) {
          $scope.selectedIDs.push(item.ID);
      });
    },
columnDefs: [
               { field: 'iSchl_Id', displayName: 'ID' },
               { field: 'vSchl_Name', displayName: 'School Name' },
               { field: 'vCity', displayName: 'City' },
               { field: 'vState', displayName: 'State' },
               { field: 'vCountry', displayName: 'Country' },
               { field: 'vEmail', displayName: 'Email' },
               { field: 'iStatus', displayName: 'Status' },
       { field: '', cellTemplate: '<button ng-click="edit(row.entity)" title="Edit" class="icon-edit edt-btn"></button><button ng-click="delete(row.entity)" title="Delete" class="icon-trash dlt-btn"></button>',displayName: 'Action'}
    ],
};
```

I have used dynamic data in grid.I have tried [How to get the cell value from ng-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911156/how-to-get-the-cell-value-from-ng-grid) Example but i not getting selectedIDs.I getting error: item are not defined

Deleteall function  :

```
$scope.deleteall = function() {
     var verify=confirm('Are you sure to want this delete all selected record?');
      if(verify==true)
      {
           //Please give me logic of selected ids
      }
    };
```